# Filter by brand loop

Tags: php

I'm making an online store and I need to filter results by brand from the database. How can I create a loop to go through all the brands because they are not only three. 
Here is the code:

```
$sortby = $_GET['sortby'];
if(!$sortby) { $sortby = 'name'; }

if($sortby == 'Brand1') 
{
    $sort_query = "WHERE category = 'Brand1";
}
else if($sortby == 'Brand2')
{
    $sort_query = "WHERE category = 'Brand2'";
}
else if($sortby == 'Brand3')
{
    $sort_query = "WHERE category = 'Brand3'";
}
else if($sortby == 'name')
{
    $sort_query = "";
}
else { unset($sortby); }

if($sortby)
{
    $select[$sortby] = 'selected';
}
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products $sort_query");
```

Comment: SQL-injection alert! You could as well write `$sql = mysql_query($_GET['query']);`. You should use PDO or mysqli with prepared statements. Here's a good [article about PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$sortby = $_GET['sortby'];
if(!$sortby) {
    $sort_query = "";
} else {
    $sort_query = "WHERE category = '".mysql_real_escape_string($sortby)."'";
}
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products $sort_query");
```

Remember: never trust the user! Always escape user input!

Also, using mysql-prefixed functions is outdated. You should check how to use mysqli.

Comment: what's the meaning of setting $sortby? this code worked but is not working at all and uses deprecated functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sortby = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sortby']) or $sortby = "name";

if($sortby != "name") {
    $sort_query = "WHERE category = '$sortby'";
    $select[$sortby] = 'selected';
} else {
    $sort_query = "";
}

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products $sort_query");
```

Comment: what do you do agains not existing values, given by users?

Comment: This is written according to the question at hand - and the query would return empty anyway if values are non-existent.

Answer (score 0):

I'll write the code like this:

```
$sortby = $_GET['sortby'];
$valid_brands = array('brand1','brand2');


if(in_array($sortby, $valid_brands)){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products where category = ?";
    $stmt = $db_usag->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param($sortby);
}
else{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
    $stmt = $db_usag->prepare($sql);
}

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

that is a pseudo code.. but is clean code without injection issues :)

Answer (score -1):

1. it's simple. Why write code so hard? php is dynamic.
2. to sort you must use `ORDER BY`, you want to filter..

here example, variable names I doesn't change.
This is only query buiding statement.

```
$sortby = $_GET['sortby'];
$sort_query = $sortby == 'name' ? "" : "WHERE category = '{$sortby}'";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products {$sort_query}");
```

Comment: @MichaelWalter BE ATTENTIVE !!! I wrote "This is only query buiding statement."... so read all post before downvotes.

Comment: You set me downvote for my downvote but Stackowerflow is a place for exchanging our stacks and knowledge, and to learn from each other, this is not kindergarten @MichaelWalter.

Comment: sorry, but you could provide a better answer if you include the information about injections or anything like this. as you can see in his post, he is not checking this. your answer is in MY opinion not so good. you downvoted my answer because it is not as fast as yours but more completed?

Comment: It's not only about speed, I spoke about performance @MichaelWalter, for example if in table million rows and only 2 brand is 'xxx', your code will select that million rows, than loops that, and maybe apache will broke the process, because max_array_size is smaller in php.ini etc...

Comment: now what about my answer @MichaelWalter , I selected that my answer is only statement from code, and user's code is statement too, because there is an array $select, which is not defined, and isn't used in code.

Comment: and finally if your php project's pattern designed correct(it's for You @MichaelWalter), you'll never check user input values in string, you'll write once for example in controller.class.php, where $_GET, $_POST and other variables will recursively checking for injections..

Answer (score -1):

You should select all avaiable brands from your database and than loop thorugh them.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `category` FROM products"
[mysql stuff]
while($cat = [assoc array]) /*use your prefered functions*/
{
    if($sortby == $cat['category']) 
    {
        $sort_query = "WHERE category = '".$cat['category']."'";
    } 
}
```

Comment: he wants to check if the brand name is valid and select all products with this ONE brand. create a query for this please.

Comment: "need to filter results by brand from the database" - sadly, nothing in the question specified that he wanted to check a brand name for it's validity, just that he needs to filter the results. Give him the benefit of the doubt to set the valid categories on his part.

Comment: "How can I create a loop to go through all the brands because they are not only three"...he wants to loop through all brands. i don't get the fault in my understanding here...

Comment: If you look at the code he's provided, it's fair to assume that he's talking about looping the user input (see the long `if` statement) and NOT distinct categories from the database. The general assumption here is he wants to know how to make that long `if` statement more efficient.

Comment: we could let him decide which answer is more fitting to his exact problem. it's not a reason to downvote or start a long discuss on a valid answer... maybe not the best answer for his probelm (cause we don't know it), but still valid.